# Laravel 9 hasMany relationship not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a model with a relationship with another model, when calling the relationship in the controller it gives me

> Exception: Property [products] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

model:

```
public function products(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(CartProduct::class,'cart_id','id');
}
```

controller

```
public function showCartOfAuth()
{
    $id =auth()->guard('customers')->user()->id;
    $cart = Cart::where('customer_id',$id)->get();
    $products = Cart::where('customer_id',$id)->products->get();
    $response = [
        'cart' => $cart,
        'items' => $products
    ];
    return response($response,200);
}
```

Comment: you would need to get a single model instance to then access the dynamic property `products` to get the relationship ... you have a query builder instance, you have not executed the query to get a result yet

Comment: @lagbox thanks ! you gave me a hint, I added first() before the products and it worked! cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this, please: `Cart::with('products')->where('customer_id',$id)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

The way you have implemented requires atleast two database queries.

One: `$cart = Cart::where('customer_id',$id)->get();`

Two: `Cart::where('customer_id',$id)->first()->products;` //maybe a third query to fetch the products

For better performance you should

```php
public function showCartOfAuth()
{
    $id =auth()->guard('customers')->user()->id;
    
    // Either Option 1
    // Possibly 2 database queries, one to fetch the Cart and another to fetch Products for the Cart
    $cart = Cart::where('customer_id',$id)->first();
    $products = $cart->products;
    $response = [
        'cart' => $cart,
        'items' => $products
    ];

    // OR Option 2
    // One database query using eager loading
    $cart = Cart::with('products')->where('customer_id', $id)->first();

    $response = ['cart' => $cart];
    return response($response,200);
}
```

If you use option 2 from above then instead of `$items` you can use `$cart->products`